# App not localhost not loading due to Mongodb connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have node app pointing at a mongodb using the connection string:

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
```

This variable is used throughout my code:

```
//When a connection to server is made from client
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

//When host connects for the first time
socket.on('host-join', (data) =>{
    
    //Check to see if id passed in url corresponds to id of game in database
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("agile_poker");
        var query = { id:  parseInt(data.id)};
        dbo.collection('sessions').find(query).toArray(function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            //A game was found with the id passed in url
            if(result[0] !== undefined){
                var gamePin = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000; //new pin for game
                games.addGame(gamePin, socket.id, false, {playersAnswered: 0, questionLive: false, gameid: data.id, question: 1}); //Creates a game with pin and host id
                var game = games.getGame(socket.id); //Gets the game data
                socket.join(game.pin);//The host is joining a room based on the pin
                console.log('Game Created with pin:', game.pin); 

                //Sending game pin to host so they can display it for players to join
                socket.emit('showGamePin', {
                    pin: game.pin
                });
            }else{
                socket.emit('noGameFound');
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Its been a year since I last ran this locally, but now when I start the app on port 3000, and I type in localhost:3000 or 192.168.0.1:3000 the app doesn't load and instead shows connection refused.

I saw that making HTTP calls to mongodb was deprecated (when I try to hit the mongodb port directly through a browser), but would that cause me the issue I'm experiencing with running my app locally?

Comment: Do you have a `mongod` process running on the same host (using port `27017`)? Is an error thrown/logged anywhere after some time (perhaps 30 seconds or so)?

Comment: I'm guessing the mongod must be running on that port as when I try to hit it over http I get the mongodb message 'It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.' I've also tried to hit port 28017 as I think it used to be the default port + 1000